# Derivation of group velocity?

Tags: waves, velocity

In the standard simplified derivation of group velocity (which can be found [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Waves/Group_Velocity)) we use two waves
$$y_1=A\sin(K_1x-\omega_1 t)$$
$$y_2=A\sin(K_2x-\omega_2 t)$$
In the proof we then get $$V_g=\frac{\Delta \omega}{\Delta k}$$
But I do not understand the step where this is then turned into
$$V_g=\frac{\mathrm{d} \omega}{\mathrm{d} k}$$
why do we assume that $\Delta \omega$ and $\Delta k$ are small? The derivation is valid in the case where they are not small, which means that
$$V_g= \frac{\mathrm{d} \omega}{\mathrm{d} k}$$ does not hold in this case and therefore does not hold in general.

Consider this example

> Let $K_1=3$ and $k_2=1$ and let us say we have relationship
> $\omega=k^3$ using my first fromula we get $V_g=13$ but using the
> second (with $\bar k=2$) we get $V_g=12$, theses are diferent.

Comment: The equation $V_g = \Delta\omega/\Delta k$ is a special case that arises because of the very simple model used. It isn't generally true. See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity#Derivation) and doubtless [many more easily Googlable articles](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=derivation%20of%20group%20velocity) for more.

Comment: @JohnRennie but why is it not true in the case of $\Delta \omega$ and $\Delta k$ been large, I can still get an equation of the form $y=2Acos(\Delta \omega t+ \Delta k x)sin( \bar \omega t+ \bar kx)$ which indicates a group veloicty of $\Delta \omega/ \Delta k$ which would not fit with the equation $d \omega / d k$

Comment: If $V_g = \Delta\omega/\Delta k$ then that means $V_g = d\omega/dk$ must also be true because you're just taking the limit of $\Delta\omega \rightarrow 0$ and $\Delta k \rightarrow 0$. However $V_g = d\omega/dk$ **does not** imply that $V_g = \Delta\omega/\Delta k$.

Comment: @JohnRennie but $V_g=\Delta \omega/\Delta k$ does not mean $V_g = d\omega/dk$ if $\Delta \omega$ and $\Delta k$ are large! Which is what I am asking, why do we assume they are small?

Comment: If $V_g=\Delta \omega/\Delta k$ is true for any size of $\Delta$ it must also be true for infinitesimally small $\Delta$. If the article you cite did the derivation for a specific value of $\Delta\omega$ and $\Delta k$ then you'd have a point, but since $\omega$ and $k$ can have any value you want you can make the deltas as small as you want.

Comment: @JohnRennie But we could also make them as large as we want, we have no good reason to make them small. My point is that if $V_g=\Delta \omega/\Delta k$ holds for any $\Delta$ i.e. including large $\Delta$ then $d \omega/dk$ cannot hold as they disagree for large $\Delta$

Comment: In the particular system of two plane waves $V_g = \Delta\omega/\Delta k$ holds for any size of $\Delta$ including the limit of $\Delta \rightarrow 0$ i.e. replacing $\Delta$ by $d$. however in general it does not. $V_g = d\omega/dk$ is always true. Have you looked at the link I provided for a more general derivation?

Comment: @JohnRennie I have looked at the general derivation and I am fine with it, it is just this simplified one I don't get, see th edit for an example of what I mean

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer to your question is that the derivation is only valid for small $\Delta k$ (corresponding to $\Delta \omega$) so that the beats have a much smaller wavenumber and frequency than the two waves that you are adding. The group velocity only makes sense if you have well defined envelope. In this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ffaybnenut , you only have a clear envelope for about $a \geq6$, so this means $\Delta k$ must be a sixth as big as $k$ or smaller for the derivation to apply. Mathematically there's nothing invalid about it, but the point is to capture physics.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that $V_g$ is different for different frequencies. $V_g$ is defined as $\frac{\mathrm{d} \omega}{\mathrm{d} k}$ for a specific frequency $\omega$. So for big phasmatic areas ($\Delta \omega$) Group velocity $\frac{\Delta \omega}{\Delta k}$ is the average of the speed of all phasmatic components in the area, so it  is close but it differs from any  individual $V_g$ within the group.