# Why do dispersive waves get wider?

Tags: waves, dispersion

Consider the two waves 
$$y_1=Acos(\omega_1 t+k_1 x), \tag{1}$$ 
$$y_2=Acos(\omega_2 t+k_2 x), \tag{2}$$

where $\omega_i=k_iv(k_i)$ for $i=1,2$ so we have a dispersive medium. Then if we take their superposition to get the wave:

$$y=2Acos(\bar {\omega}t + \bar {k}x)cos\left(\frac{\Delta \omega \ t}{2} + \frac{\Delta k \ x}{2}\right), \tag{3}$$

where

$$\bar {\omega} = \frac {\omega  _1 + \omega  _2}{2}, \ \ \ \bar {k} = \frac {k_1 + k_2}{2}, \tag{4}$$

$$\Delta \omega = \omega  _1 - \omega  _2, \ \ \ \Delta k = k_1 - k_2. \tag{5}$$

Then the waves in wave packets are ment to spread out. Why? In this case at any time $t=t_0$ the wavelength of the wavepacket is given by $\lambda=4 \pi /(k_1+k_2)$ which is a constant and therefore the wavepackets should stay the same length, so why do they spread out?

Comment: This isn't a wave packet, it's just a superposition of two plane-waves. A wave packet needs some spacial envelope (which is the thing that spreads out)

Comment: @Shep why is $2Acos((\omega_1-\omega_2)t/2+(k_1-k_2)x/2)$ not my envelope?

Comment: I suppose that's a fine envelope. But more importantly, this wave packet is already as "spread out" as it possibly could be: it's periodic out to $\pm$ infinity. For an example of a function with a (finite) envelope, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet#Dispersive

Comment: @Shep do you mind looking at my other question http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/165060/, along with the coments.

Comment: Related questions by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/164829/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/164909/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/165060/2451

Comment: Take a look at http://physics.usask.ca/~hirose/ep225/animation/dispersion/anim-dispersion.html - it shows some nice animations of dispersive and non-dispersive wave packets. It will help you get an intuition for this.

Comment: The dispersion can be seen, not with a superposition of two waves but with more. A wave-packet of finite width disperses during the time. A simple example is a Gaussian wave-packet which at $t=0$ may have a small width and high peak, but, as the time passes the width will increase and the peak will become lower. 
That is due to the fact that a small width Gaussian has a big spread in the values of $k$. Bottom line, a wave-packet contains many values of $k$ and with the widening of such a wave-packet can you see dispersion.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, we say that waves are dispersive if their phase velocity if a function of wavenumber. That is,
$$c\equiv \frac{\omega}{k}=c(k).$$

What you've sketched above is an argument related to the group velocity. The key property of dispersion is the functional form of the angular frequency $\omega$. The relationship $\omega$ has with $k$, called a dispersion relationship, is related to the properties of the medium. For deep water surface gravity waves $\omega=\sqrt{gk}$, hence $c$ is dispersive.

This means that waves of different wavelengths travel at different speeds, and hence if you had an initially compact wave group, it would spread out.

This is why, for example, when swell comes to shore it is the longest period waves (ie the fastest waves) that reach shore first. The swell will last a certain amount of time, with progressively shorter waves coming to shore.

For shallow water linear waves $\omega = \sqrt{gh}k$ with $h$ the depth of the water. The phase velocity of these waves is independent of $k$, hence all of these waves travel at the same speed, and a packet of waves will not disperse.